# Check Sql queries injected in post data

Tags: node.js, sql-injection

How to check JSON post body data is injected with any SQL queries?

```
Post data:
{
 name: 'xyz', 
 host: 'localhost', 
 port: 3001,
 path: '/samp',
 sql: 'insert into table1 values.......'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the which mySQL node.js library you're using.  If you're using this one https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql then you just have to use either:

```
connection.escape()
```

or

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?',
[personID],
function(selectErr,selectRow) { 
});
```

Comment: Im using couch DB. I want to protect the data from injecting sql queries by external user

Comment: Then you'll probably need some fun regex to find/replace all possibly malicious characters.